# Modify permissions / immovable folder w/o chattr

Tags: permissions

I have a server where I have folders to be shared over local network (like Photos, Music etc.). I did the following:

```
cd /volumes1/Family/Photos
touch .chattrlock
sudo chattr +i .chattrlock
```

Now I cannot delete the folder "Photos" but I can still move it within the Family Share. Is there a way to prevent the Folder from being moved inside the share?

The folder's permissions should stay `rwx`.

Comment: Is it your goal to be able to add content to `Photos`?  If so, `chattr +i` will be problematic.

Comment: Yes Timothy, I want to create new stuff inside Photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a folder itself is not immutable but one or more files inside of it are then you can't delete it but you can, in fact, move or modify it.

If you want to make it so that the `Photos` folder itself can't being moved or deleted but you still want to create files inside of it then you'll need the following command:

`chattr +a Photos`

That will make it so that the folder can't be renamed, moved, or deleted but will allow you to create and modify files inside of it unless the files themselves are immutable. If you want to delete files inside then you'll need to first `chattr -a Photos` and then `chattr +a Photos` after you're done.

Comment: Thanks @Nasir, but in fact I can't create any new folder inside "Photos".

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that :) I stumbled the man-pages but somehow I did not come accross this

Comment: The man page doesn't actually give any details on what the `a` flag does for directories. It only says what it does for files. The only way to find out is by trial and error.